# .NET WebBrowser download file after login form

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I would consult a problem that I have to solve for a client. We need to capture data from a provider after a login form, and we have to download a text file produced by a script that is innacesible if not passed before the login form ... To do this, we need to use the WebBrowser control. The discharge must take place automatically, without displaying the download dialog control but we can not control it. We've been trying to fix it, but found the way to go.

We are using fw 2. Thank you very much in advance.

PS: if someone comes up with an alternative to this, will be welcome ...

Answer (score 0):

Why use a `WebBrowser`? Take a look at the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class, and especially its [`CookieContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) property, which lets you log in to most applications using cookies for identification. If it uses another kind of login, take a look at the [`Credentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx) property.

Comment: To download the file, you must have logged before in a typical form with username and password. I tried to emulate the cookies, the agent and even the referer and not get into. How can use HttpWebRequest to perform this feat? Thank you very much.